# What HTML5 features/attribute does JQuery mobile used?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, mobile-website

Anyone know What HTML5 features/attribute does JQuery mobile used?
.I've looked on the website and I can't seem to find out which ones. 
Or how would I find out?
THanks

Answer (score 1):

The framework heavily uses the new HTML5 **data-** tag attributes.

It is used to define everything from mobile pages, header/footer elements, to icon positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from their documentation:

> HTML5 Markup-driven configuration of
>   pages and behavior for fast
>   development and minimal required
>   scripting. Automatic initialization by
>   using HTML5 data-role attributes in
>   the HTML markup to act as the trigger
>   to automatically initialize all jQuery
>   Mobile widgets found on a page.